# Postgresql trigger notification

Tags: sql, postgresql

Please help me to correct sql statement:

```
CREATE TRIGGER transaction_insert
    AFTER INSERT ON transaction
    FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN (NEW.tr_type = 55)
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE pg_notify('check_close', to_char(NEW.n_transaction, 999999));
```

I need to receive notification when row with `tr_type=55` is added.
`tr_type` is `int`. n_transaction is `int`.

Postgresql 8.3.4

Please help!

Comment: Please note that "tramsaction" is a reserved word. Naming a table "transaction" is a bad choice.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
CREATE TRIGGER transaction_insert
    AFTER INSERT ON transaction
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE transaction_insert_check_close();


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION transaction_insert_check_close() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $transaction_insert_check_close$
BEGIN
    IF (NEW.tr_type = 55) THEN
        PERFORM pg_notify('check_close', to_char(NEW.n_transaction, 999999));
    END IF;

    RETURN NEW;
END;

$transaction_insert_check_close$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```